# How to take the values from a componentDidUpdate() and save it so that i can use it later for displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default class newroom extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       currentUser:NaN,
       rooms:NaN
    }

  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    // console.log(prevState)
    const {currentUser}  = nextProps
    return {currentUser}
  }


  componentDidUpdate(){
    const {...currentUser} = this.state.currentUser
    currentUser.getJoinableRooms()
            .then((rooms)=>{
              //this rooms has a id and a name which i want to store so that i can display in the h3 tag
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="new-room">
        <h3>{}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The getDerivedStateFromProps() method returns the currentUser object and sets the state,
and when ever the curentUser updates the componentDidUpdate method fires and gets the rooms object but i cant figure out how i will store the rooms.id & rooms.name so that i can later display in in the h3 tag.If i use the setState in the componentDidUpdate() the state is updated each time and the method is fired again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare current props with previous props before calling getJoinableRooms

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevProps.currentUser.id !== this.props.currentUser.id){
         this.props.currentUser.getJoinableRooms()
            .then((rooms)=>{
                //set state here
         })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))

     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `getDerivedStateFromProps`, and do your fetches in your componentDidMount method (When it's first mounted):

```
export default class newroom extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       rooms:NaN
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const { currentUser } = this.props

    currentUser.getJoinableRooms()
            .then((rooms)=>{
              this.setState({rooms})
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="new-room">
        {rooms.map(room => <h3 key={room.id}>{room.id}</h3>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```